# Diffing 2 arrays, i.e which items to add and remove

Tags: javascript

Given:

- array of "current" objects `[{id: '1'},{id: '2'},{id: '3'},{id: '4'},{id: '5'}]`
- array of "new" objects `[{id: '1'},{id: '5'},{id: '6'},{id: '7'},{id: '8'}]`

How to determine which objects

- to add (not in "current") and
- to remove (not in "new")?

In this case:

- `{id: '2'},{id: '3'},{id: '4'}` should be removed
- `{id: '6'},{id: '7'},{id: '8'}` should be added

Performance is not extremely important, my dataset is usually around 200.

**Edit:** I need to know about elements to be added/removed because "current" array correlates to DOM nodes and I don't just want to delete them all and add from scratch - already tried that and performance is far from perfect.

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: Why not just replace "current" array with "new" array like `currentArray = newArray;`?

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir "current" array correlates to DOM nodes, I have to remove old DOM nodes and for that I need to know which ones. Yeah, my bad for forgetting this important fact.

Comment: @Solo you should show us exactly what you want to do and the real data you are working with, not give us an example with dummy objects. I'm assuming you want the objects to be removed from the DOM as well as from the array, but with the examples in your question, any solution will be just an iteration of the replace the "current" array with the "new" array.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir My code still operates on objects in arrays, performing DOM mutations is just a side effect, so I think that it would be pointless and confusing extra code.

Comment: @Solo does removing the object from the array (using `splice` for example) causes the DOM element to be removed from the DOM tree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both cases, this is a classic use case of the set operation "difference". All you need to do is define a difference function, and then apply it with `current.difference(new)` and `new.difference(current)`.

```js
function difference(a, b, compare) {
  let diff = [];
  for (let ai = 0; ai < a.length; ai++) {
    let exists = false;
    for (let bi = 0; bi < b.length; bi++) {
      if (compare(a[ai], b[bi])) {
        exists = true;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (!exists) diff.push(a[ai]);
  }

  return diff;
}

function getRemoved(oldA, newA) {
  return difference(oldA, newA, (a, b) => a.id == b.id);
}

function getAdded(oldA, newA) {
  return difference(newA, oldA, (a, b) => a.id == b.id);
}

let current = [{id: '1'}, {id: '2'}, {id: '3'}, {id: '4'}, {id: '5'}];
let newArr = [{id: '1'}, {id: '5'}, {id: '6'}, {id: '7'}, {id: '8'}];

console.log(getRemoved(current, newArr));
console.log(getAdded(current, newArr));
```

Answer (score 1):

- For each item in current that is not found in new. That item is deleted.
- For each item in new that is not in current. That item is added.

You run the run these checks in two different loops one after the other.

Comment: So simple, yet so effective. I was thinking maybe there's a way without creating new "helper" arrays to keep track of things (to avoid garbage) but I guess I could reuse them.

Comment: You don't need helper arrays. You literally run a check 2N^2 time complexity set of checks. There are absolutely ways to do this better, especially if the elements are sorted which it looks like they are. But, that's so little data things are better to be simple. Especially because when you tend to do these operations you typically need to do some processing on each item. Like announce to some systems that this thing is added and this one that those are removed. It's the reason you'd do this rather than just using the new list directly.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Set` data structure to calculate the different and filter the expeced values (using its `has` method). Time complexity for this approach will be linear (`O(n)`)

`Set` use hash table so complexity for retrival/lookup is `O(1)` ([doc](https://wiki.mozilla.org/User:Jorend/Deterministic_hash_tables), *Theory > Lookup Speed*)

```js
const prev = [{ id: "1" }, { id: "2" }, { id: "3" }, { id: "4" }, { id: "5" }] // length n
const current = [
  { id: "1" },
  { id: "5" },
  { id: "6" },
  { id: "7" },
  { id: "8" },
] // length m

const prevIdSet = new Set(prev.map((o) => o.id)) // O(n)
const currentIdSet = new Set(current.map((o) => o.id)) // O(m)

function difference(setA, setB) {
  let _difference = new Set(setA)
  for (let elem of setB) {
    _difference.delete(elem)
  }
  return _difference
}

const removedIdSet = difference(prevIdSet, currentIdSet) // O(m)
const addedIdSet = difference(currentIdSet, prevIdSet) // O(n)

const removed = prev.filter((o) => removedIdSet.has(o.id)) // O(n)
const added = current.filter((o) => addedIdSet.has(o.id)) // O(m)

console.log("removed", removed)
console.log("added", added)

// Total complexity O(constantA * n + constantB * m) ~ O(n + m)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could go with something like this :

```js
const currentElements = [{id: '1'},{id: '2'},{id: '3'},{id: '4'},{id: '5'}]

const newElements = [{id: '1'},{id: '5'},{id: '6'},{id: '7'},{id: '8'}]

const elementsToAdd = newElements.filter(e1 => !currentElements.find(e2 => e2.id === e1.id))
const elementsToRemove = currentElements.filter(e1 => !newElements.find(e2 => e2.id === e1.id))

console.log({elementsToAdd, elementsToRemove})
```

Basically, I take an array, and find the elements not contained in the other array.

For the elements to add, check the elements in newElements that are not in currentElements, and vice versa.

Comment: [Array#some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) or [Array#every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) are better fitted for this job than `Array#find`

Answer (score 0):

You could use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter). Something like this for items to remove:

```
arr1.filter(function(i) {return arr2.indexOf(i) < 0;});
```

And swap the arrays for items to add. For example:

```js
let arr1 = [{id: '1'},{id: '2'},{id: '3'},{id: '4'},{id: '5'}];
let arr2 = [{id: '1'},{id: '5'},{id: '6'},{id: '7'},{id: '8'}];

arr1 = arr1.map((obj) => obj.id);
arr2 = arr2.map((obj) => obj.id);

console.log("Remove these IDs: ", arr1.filter(function(i) {return arr2.indexOf(i) < 0;}));
console.log("Add these IDs: ", arr2.filter(function(i) {return arr1.indexOf(i) < 0;}));
```

Answer (score 0):

You you only needs the ids: You could extract the ids with `flatMap` and than `filter` with `every` for not `incudes`.

```js
let old = [{id: '1'},{id: '2'},{id: '3'},{id: '4'},{id: '5'}];
let act = [{id: '1'},{id: '5'},{id: '6'},{id: '7'},{id: '8'}];

let oldIds = old.flatMap(el => el.id);
let actIds = act.flatMap(el => el.id);

let add = actIds.filter(id => oldIds.every(old=> !old.includes(id)));
let del = oldIds.filter(id => actIds.every(act=> !act.includes(id)));
console.log('Add: ', add);
console.log('Del: ', del);
```